# Cannot figure out what's wrong with my eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, e-commerce

So I'm creating an ecommerce website for a project. I've been following a tutorial on youtube. I seem to be having trouble with the script for the project. I've double checked my code, and it's the same as the tutorial, however, the script doesn't run at all.

```js
/* Showing the navigation Menu */

const showMenu = (toggleId, navId) => {
  const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId)

  if (toggle && nav) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      nav.classList.toggle('show')
    })
  }
}

showMenu('nav-toggle', 'nav-menu')

const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link'),
  navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')

function linkAction() {

  navMenu.classList.remove('show')

}

navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction))
```

```css
:root {
  /*Header*/
  --header-height: 48px;
  /*Font*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  --font-bold: 700;
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --big-font-size: 20px;
  --bigger-font-size: 24px;
  --biggest-font-size: 32px;
  --h2-font-size: 25px;
  --normal-font-size: 15px;
  --smaller-font-size: 13px;
  /*Colours*/
  --dark-color: #141414;
  --dark-color-light: #8a8a8a;
  --dark-color-lighten: #f2f2f2;
  --white-color: #fff;
  /*Margins*/
  --mb-1: 10px;
  --mb-2: 16px;
  --mb-3: 24px;
  --mb-4: 32px;
  --mb-5: 40px;
  --mb-6: 48px;
  --z-fixed: 100;
  --rotate-img: rotate(-30deg);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   :root {
    --big-font-size: 24px;
    --bigger-font-size: 32px;
    --biggest-font-size: 48px;
    --normal-font-size: 16px;
    --smaller-font-size: 14px;
  }
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  /*margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;*/
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--dark-color);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
pl,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--dark-color);
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.section {
  padding: 80px 0px 32px;
}

.section-title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
}

.section-title::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 56px;
  height: 2.88px;
  top: -16px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: var(--dark-color);
}

.bd-grid {
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  column-gap: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  margin-left: var(--mb-2);
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
}

.l-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: var(--dark-color-lighten);
}

.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--header-height);
    left: -100%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 32px;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
}

.nav_item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.nav_logo {
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

.nav_toggle,
.nav_shop {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<!--ICONS-->
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<header class="1-header" id="header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div class="nav_toggle" id="nav-toggle">
      <i class='bx bxs-grid'></i>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="nav_logo">Roby</a>
    <div class="nav_menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav_list">
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav_link"></a>Home</li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#featured" class="nav_link"></a>Featured</li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#women" class="nav_link"></a>Women</li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#new" class="nav_link"></a>New</li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#shop" class="nav_link"></a>Shop</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav_shop">
      <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main class="1-main">

</main>
```

The navigation menu needs to open when the grid icon in the top left is clicked, but it doesn't. It also needs to disappear when clicked again.

I can post the link to the youtube video as well, although it's my first time posting on stackoverflow, so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to.

Please advise.

Comment: You're missing the style to switch display , add  and test: `.nav_menu {display:none;}
.nav_menu.show {display:block;}`. or check https://jsfiddle.net/8n3cm46L/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I added and tested the display style, didn't work. Then I checked out your code on jsfiddle, copied and pasted it into new files and ran it on chrome, didn't work either. But the your code works in jsfiddle. Just isn't working for me.

Comment: I have turned your code into a snippet, can you add/remove what's similar to your page so it reproduce your issue. (snippet seems to work too)

Comment: It's fine. I haven't managed to make the script work, but I started another site from scratch, I don't need this one anymore. Thanks for your assistance though. Much appreciated.